# Calculation time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to calculate time complexity of this algorithm but I'm really struggling trying to understand how many times each will execute. I would really appreciate explanation on how to think when doing these exercises not just this one in particular

```
int SortRight(A, i) {
n= len(A);
if (i == n-1) return A;
for (j= (i + 1); j < n; j++) {
if (A[i] < A[j]) { temp= A[i]; A[i]= A[j]; A[j]= temp; } }
  return SortRight(A, i+1)
}
```

the comments are how many time I think the lines execute but I'm pretty sure this is wrong

```
int SortRight(A, i) { //n+1
n= len(A); //n+1
if (i == n-1) //n+1
{return A;} /1
for (j= (i + 1); j < n; j++) { // (1) n*(n-1)
if (A[i] < A[j]) { temp= A[i]; A[i]= A[j]; A[j]= temp; } } // i have no idea for this part 
  return SortRight(A, i+1)
}
```

(1) Assume at one point j>=n so that would be when i=k so j=k+1 => k+1=n k=n-1, (n-1) times the number of times that the rec. call will execute ->n => n*(n-1)

Comment: The part you commented is just constant work. This is a classic `1 + 2 + ... + n = n * (n+1)/2` which makes it roughly `O(n^2)`

Comment: @user1984 but if i is not 0 is that still true?

Comment: If in the initial call to `SortRight`, `i` is not `0`, the sum would become `1 + 2 + ... (n-i)`. But in Big O, you care about the worst case scenario. Otherwise, you could always think about scenarios, where the calculations aren't true, because of a special case.

Comment: You have to consider n to be len(A) - i, and then the recurrence relation (for the number of element comparisons) is T(n) = n - 1 + T(n-1).

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite with the constant-time operations replaced by "Cst" (every Cst is different):

```
int SortRight(A, i) {
Cst;
if (i == n-1)
  Cst;
else
  for (j= (i + 1); j < n; j++) { Cst; }

return SortRight(A, i+1); }
```

Now rewrite, replacing all operations by by the time they take:

```
S(i)= (
  a +
  if (i == n-1)
    b
  else
    (n - i - 1) * c
  + S(i+1))
```

This is a first-order recurrence, which we put in a more usual form:

```
S(n-1) = a + b
S(i) = S(i+1) + a + (n - i - 1) * c
```

We can solve iteratively,

```
S(n-1) = a + b
S(n-2) = S(n-1) + a + (n - (n - 2) - 1) c = 2a + b + c
S(n-3) = S(n-2) + a + (n - (n - 3) - 1) c = 3a + b + 3c
S(n-4) = S(n-3) + a + (n - (n - 4) - 1) c = 4a + b + 6c
....
```

You can check that the respective coefficients are `n-1-i`, `1`, `T[n-1-i]`, where `T` denotes a triangular number. In particular,

```
S(0) = (n-1).a + b + T[n-1].c
```

---

**Advanced note:**

In fact, the body of the loop does not take constant time: it can be the time for just a comparison, say `c'` or a comparison and a swap, `c' + c"`. The respective counts depends on the initial ordering of the array, which we don't know. Anyway we can write

```
S(0) = (n-1).a + b + T[n-1].c' + N(A).c"
```

where `N(A)` denotes the number of swaps performed, which is also the initial number of inversions in the array.